# Invalid bundle when uploading to itunes connect after removing framework that are marked as optional

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have a 3rd party dynamic framework thats listed in "Link binary with libraries" But I've marked it as optional. I have a fastlane script to remove said framework from the embed phase. The build is fine, but when trying to upload to itunes connect, its rejected with the following message:

```
Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are 
referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path.
```

Other similar questions require you to add the actual framework into the embed phase. But it is my intent to remove it.

Comment: Why is it there in the first place? Is it needed for debug builds? What if you unchecked the "Archive" box in the build scheme for the framework?

Comment: The project has several schemes. Some schemes require it the framework some, some do not. @dfd

Comment: You can't link to an embedded library that isn't there. What harm does it do to leave the framework there?

Comment: Even if its marked as optional? (and its an dynamic framework) Becuase the app will deploy to a device perfectly fine, the complaint only comes from itunes connect.